# How to write scraped data into well adjusted columns?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently scraping data using BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to write the scraped data into a file where I want to make well adjusted columns.

Here is what my current code produces:

```
1997       Fisrt Round         Sampras, Pete       Reneberg, Richey        4-6, 6-4, 6-3, 6-3
1997       Fisrt Round         Philippoussis, Mark       Frana, Javier        4-6, 6-4, 6-3, 6-3
1997       Fisrt Round         Goossens, Kris       Black, Byron        4-6, 6-4, 6-3, 6-3
...
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
1997       Fisrt Round         Sampras, Pete             Reneberg, Richey        4-6, 6-4, 6-3, 6-3
1997       Fisrt Round         Philippoussis, Mark       Frana, Javier           4-6, 6-4, 6-3, 6-3
1997       Fisrt Round         Goossens, Kris            Black, Byron            4-6, 6-4, 6-3, 6-3
...
```

Here is my code:

```
for tournamentYear_url in tournamentYear_urls:
    i = 0
    tournamentYear+=1
    soup = make_soup(tournamentYear_url)
    while i < len(get_player_name_first_round(soup)):
        mon_fichier.write(str(tournamentYear) + "       ")
        mon_fichier.write(str("Fisrt Round         "))
        mon_fichier.write(get_player_name_first_round(soup)[i] + "       ")
        mon_fichier.write(get_player_name_first_round(soup)[i+1] + "        ")
        mon_fichier.write(get_player_score_first_round_winner(soup) + "\n")
        i+=2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Python's [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

There's a part specifically about text alignment and field width/padding:

> **'<'**   - Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this is the default for most objects).
>
> **'>'** - Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this is the default for numbers).
>
> **'='** - Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits. This is used for printing fields in the form ‘+000000120’. This alignment option is only valid for numeric types.
>
> **'^'** - Forces the field to be centered within the available space.

and some examples from the docs on how to use [**format()**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> '{:<30}'.format('left aligned')
'left aligned                  '
>>> '{:>30}'.format('right aligned')
'                 right aligned'
>>> '{:^30}'.format('centered')
'           centered           '
>>> '{:*^30}'.format('centered')  # use '*' as a fill char
'***********centered***********'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I am unable to make it work.

Here is my code :
    
mon_fichier.write(str(get_tournament_prizemoney(soup)))
    '{:>30}'.format(mon_fichier.write(str(get_tournament_surface(soup))+"\n"))

and i get :

€10,104,000Clay

and I expected :

€10,104,000  [     tab     ]  Clay

Comment: Try moving the formatting part inside the write call. At least from what I get from your comment, your problem is you write it first to the output/file without formatting.

Comment: You've removed all the padding, you need to use it like: `{Player1:<30}`